# Outlook 2016 disable certificate checking

Tags: email, outlook

I have a Gmail account that i managed from Windows Live Mail without any problem.
Now i use Outlook 2016 but every time i open it, it informs me that Gmail's certificate can't be verified. 
I found many answers in web for other versions but none for 2016.
I create a registry key,as somebody suggested  (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Security  SupressNameChecks=1) but still nothing.
Any idea please ?

Answer (score 4):

In case nobody has found an answer to this yet:

The correct Registry key name is `SuppressNameChecks`. That's TWO `p` characters in `Suppress`.

Spent an hour in frustration pulling my hair out wondering why this setting wasn't working until I decided to, just in case, try using a different spelling than what the internet is telling me. Et voila, certificate errors - gone.

Comment: Thanks for your hit. Some time ago i reinstalled windows and office 2016 and I haven't this problem anymore. I don't know if this was the solution or something else. Just for sure, i create the registry key.

Comment: Are you sure about that? It looks like [Microsoft also prescribes `SupressNameChecks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/outlook/troubleshoot/security/how-to-turn-off-email-matching-for-certificates). It would be good, perhaps, to do some "scientific" testing to figure out if this works or if it's just a cargo-culting artifact. (I cannot test this myself, as I do not have administrator access on any machine I operate which is licensed for Office.)

Answer (score 4):

[See this page for information about Outlook 2016 / Office 365
Certificate Error Handling.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3211279/outlook-2016-implementation-of-autodiscover)

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
Value: ShowCertErrors
Default: 0
Data: 1 = Show certificate warnings/errors; 0 = Don't show certificate warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I had the opposite - two 'p's did not solve the issue, but one 'p' did.  I left both keys in there in case different sections of code use different keys.  I was getting the error right at startup, but then again every half hour or so (not every time mail was syncing)

Comment: SupressNameChecks (with whatever number of 'p's) is also listed regarding email S/MIME signature/encryption certificate checking, e.g. at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/276597/how-to-turn-off-e-mail-matching-for-certificates-in-outlook

Answer (score 0):

I have several domains hosted on Bluehost and this nag was becoming a real nuisance. I tried all of the methods stated on several channels, none of which worked. I looked at the certificate and made a note of the server for which the certificate was issued and changed my server settings in outlook to match. Tried sending and receiving to make sure they were valid, and bingo. No more nags.